# Html.TextBoxFor() does not generate any html markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got 4 shared EditorTemplates: Tab, Group, Line & Item.

**Tab.cshtml**:

```
@model AWMCCRM.Web.ViewModels.Tab
@Html.HiddenFor(vm => vm.Name)
<div id="tab-@Model.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty)" class="tab-content">
     @Html.EditorFor(vm => vm.Groups)
</div>
```

**Group.cshtml**:

```
@model AWMCCRM.Web.ViewModels.Group
@Html.HiddenFor(vm => vm.Name)
<fieldset>
    <legend>@Model.Name</legend>
    @Html.EditorFor(vm => vm.Lines)
</fieldset>
```

**Line.cshtml**:

```
@model AWMCCRM.Web.ViewModels.Line
@Html.HiddenFor(vm => vm.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(vm => vm.Items)
```

**Item.cshtml**:

```
@model AWMCCRM.Web.ViewModels.Item

<div class="@Model.DivClass">
    <p class="@Model.PClass">
        Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.ValueString, Model.Name);
        Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.ValueString);
    </p>
</div>
```

Corresponding **ViewModels**:

```
public class Tab
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}
public class Line
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ValueString { get; set; }
    public string DivClass { get; set; }
    public string PClass { get; set; }
}
```

In my main **View** I have this:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(vm => vm.Tabs)
```

The code that gets generated looks like this:

```
<div id="tab-Tab-1" class="tab-content">
<input id="Tabs_0__group_Name" name="Tabs[0].group.Name" type="hidden" value="Group0" />
<fieldset>
    <legend>Group0</legend>
<input id="Tabs_0__group_line_Name" name="Tabs[0].group.line.Name" type="hidden" value="Line0" />
<div class="_20">
    <p class="">
    </p>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

As you can see, the div and the p gets generated, but there is no textbox or label.

I have also tried this in the item template instead, but it didn't work either:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(vm => Model.ValueString);
```

Any ideas why or what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure that the Model is not null.

Comment: @UmairP, I've just double checked and the Model is not null. It has a value and so does Model.ValueString. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I'm almost too embarrassed to post the solution but here it is...

I was missing the '@' in the beginning of the lines;

in my item.cshtml

```
    Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.ValueString, Model.Name);
    Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.ValueString);
```

should be

```
    @Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.ValueString, Model.Name);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.ValueString);
```